# Why do sitemaps generated by different plugins look so different from each other?

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, sitemap, plugin

This is my first time generating a sitemap. I used two plugins to compare sitemaps.

Yoast generated a normal looking sitemap. But the sitemap generated by Google XML Sitemaps plugin looks weird (see image below). I'd prefer to use Brachhold's plugin, but the sitemap looks weird, is it supposed to look like this? Will Google Webmasters Tools accept this weird looking sitemap?

[image: Wierd Sitemap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dashes in front of the `<urlset` and `<url>` does not look right and should throw an error. As well, while the `xsi:` may be correct, I cannot tell you that Google will recognize it.

You can find out what Google says about sitemaps here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en

The Yoast sitemap is likely correct and I would trust it. Yoast has a very fine reputation. I would not trust the sitemap in your example. But there is one way to be sure.

You can test your sitemap using Google Webmaster Tools > Crawl > Sitemaps > Add/Test Sitemap.